# How to create multiple subsets of a dataset using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a fairly large dataset and I want to create n amount of subsets of that particular dataset.

I know the start and end points of each subset (the start and end points of each subset are in two different vectors called "start" and "ends", respectively).

I can create a subset manually by inputting:

**Dataset_n <- Dataset [ start[n] : ends[n], ]**

However, since I need to create many different subsets, this is quite a tedious process.

Is there a way to automate this by using maybe a loop?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to create the sequence from each corresponding element of 'start' and 'end' to create the subset of 'Dataset' in a `list`

```
lst <- Map(function(x, y) Dataset[x:y,], start, ends)
```

---

Or this can be done by looping through the sequence of 'start', and then subset based on the index and subset the 'Dataset'

```
lst <- lapply(seq_along(start), function(i) Dataset[start[i]:ends[i],])
```

---

Or this can be done with a `for` loop by initializing a `list` and then assign the subset to `list` elements

```
lst <- vector("list", length(start))
for(i in seq_along(start)) {
     lst[[i]] <- Dataset[start[i]:ends[i], ]
 }
```